# C# client connection, Socket Exception:The system detected an invalid pointer address

Tags: c#, sockets, networking, ipv6, ipv4

I've written a server and client in C# .net 4.6 that should accept both ipv6 and ipv4 connections. The relevant code for the server listener is as follows:

```
            listener = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetworkV6,
            SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        listener.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.IPv6, SocketOptionName.IPv6Only, false);
        listener.DualMode = true;

        // Bind the socket to the local endpoint and listen for incoming connections.
        try
        {
            listener.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.IPv6Any, 3425));
            listener.Listen(100);
```

And the client connects like this:

```
        socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.Unspecified, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
    try
    {
        IPAddress[] ip = Dns.GetHostAddresses(ipAddress);


        StatusBoxHandler.statusText = "Connecting...";

        IPEndPoint remoteEP = new IPEndPoint(ip[0], port);
        Debug.Log(ip[0]);
        socket.Connect(remoteEP);
```

I've had no problems so far with 3 different people trying to connect to this server with the given client. The fourth person, who is running Windows 8.1 however is having a bit of difficulty.

He is unable to ping the server with the hostname as it says destination unreachable, and he is unable to ping the servers ipv6 address, giving the error:

> PING: transmit failed, general failure.

He is however able to ping the ipv4 address successfully. The weird bit with this is that he has ipV6 enabled and I have verified this.

When attempting to connect with the client and forcing it to use the ipv4 address he obtains the error:

> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: The system detected an invalid pointer address in attempting to use a pointer argument in a call.

I've also verified that in the log it's connecting to the exact same ipv4 address that mine would use to connect, so it's not a matter of it obtaining the wrong ip address. Additionally, I've connected from the client to the server successfully with ipv6, ipv4 and the dns hostname addresses and they all work fine for my machine and two others.

Is there some sort of problem in my code that I'm missing or is there just some sort of strange unrelated issue that is only affecting his machine?

Comment: I'd say it is a problem with IPv6 in his network, how did you verify that his equipment is IPv6 enabled?

Comment: Why are you using SocketOptionName.IPv6Only?  Use IPAny (not IPv6Any).

Comment: @jdweng as i remember right that is an older method to set a socket into dual mode before the `listener.DualMode` was implemented.

Comment: @Oxados I had a look at his windows tcp/ip configuration for his network adapter and it had ipv6 enabled. He also had an ipv6 ip address when running ipconfig /all

Comment: @Toofy may it be possible, that what you saw was the link local address? (begins with fe80). It's the way ping fails, that lets me believe that the os doesn't know that to do with it.

Comment: @Oxados I had another look and there's a fe80::1x3 dns server listed for his wireless adapter, but there is also a valid ipv6 address on this same adapter. That should mean it's working, right?

Answer (score 0):

The way IP addess is being retrieved is not correct. Instead use below way

```
var ipHostInfo = Dns.GetHostEntry("localhost"); 
var ipAddress = ipHostInfo.AddressList.FirstOrDefault(a => a.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork);
```